# Not able to pass Integer in JSONParser

Tags: apex, json, jsongenerator

I am passing the integer value in JSON test class, however the test class is failing with this exception.

System.JSONException: Current token (VALUE_STRING) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors at input location [1,896]

Here is my code:-
Test class

```
        '   \"orgTypeOther\":\"Other\",'+
    '   \"sicCode\":\"5112\",'+
```

Here sicCode  is  5112,  which is  part of the request json created in test class, and in actul class

```
                    } else if (text == 'orgTypeOther') {
                    orgTypeOther = parser.getText();
                } else if (text == 'sicCode') {
                    sicCode = parser.getIntegerValue();
                }
```

Here sicCode is Integer.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: That is not a valid json for integer. Valid JSON would be \"sicCode\": 5112,'

Comment: Ohh I see.. thanks.. that solved the issue. btw it was automatically generated by JSON2Apex Heroku app